# Display javascript result which is result on differences between dates inside input tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am new and learning programming languages,
here I want to ask on how to place javascript result (date) into input tag html.

the result seems not appear inside the input tag.

here is the function I wrote:

```
function updatesum() {
    var d1= new Date(document.getElementById("d1").value;);
    var d2 = new Date(document.getElementById("d2").value;);
    var total = (d2.getDate() - d1.getDate()) / 30 +
d2.getMonth() - d1.getMonth() +
(12 * (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()));
    // alert(total);
    document.getElementById("txtTotal").value = total;
    return false;
}
```

and this is the html form:

```
<br>
<form name="input" action="#" method="get" onsubmit="return false;" >
Start date:<input  class= "d1" type="text" name="d1" value="" id="d1" />
End Date:<input  class="d2" type="text" name="d2" value="" id="d2" />
<br>
<br>
Total Month in fraction:<input type="text" name="total" value=" " 
id="txtTotal"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="updatesum()"/>
</form>
```

the result of the function should be in input form

https://jsfiddle.net/syafieqq/c8L68bjj/2/

**UPDATE** correct answer

http://jsfiddle.net/syafieqq/69m3LkLv/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code :

```html
<header> date format ex: 2010/11/23</header>
<br>
<form name="input" action="#" method="get" onsubmit="return false;" >
  Start date:<input  class= "d1" type="text" name="d1" value="" id="d1" />
  End Date:<input  class="d2" type="text" name="d2" value="" id="d2" />
  <br>
  <br>
  Total Month in fraction:<input type="text" name="total" value=" " id="txtTotal"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="updatesum()"/>
</form>

<script>
  function updatesum() {
    var d1= new Date(document.getElementById("d1").value); // was value;); removed inner ;
    var d2 = new Date(document.getElementById("d2").value); // was value;); removed inner ;

    var total = (d2.getDate() - d1.getDate()) / 30 +
        d2.getMonth() - d1.getMonth() +
        (12 * (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()));
    // alert(total);
    document.getElementById("txtTotal").value = total;
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: wow, its work.. i dont realize that typo,  thanks a lot... already tested in my local server,, but, i just wonder, why, in jsfiddle the result still does not appear..?

Comment: Do not write the javascript in the javascript section in jsfiddle while using html's `onclick` attribute, if you write it in the javascript section, use javascript's `addEventListener` event. If you use html's `onclick`, write the javascript in a `script` tag in the same page as the html.